# How to accessing mapState in Vuex and render it to view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

i’m trying to return all data from API to my views with Axios and using Vuex to store my state.
This source code can return ‘’‘console.log’’’ but it can’t pass to view.

I had try change mounted() to change() but it still don't working

Here my source code :
In ‘./store/modules/form.js’ :

```
import Vue from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

const state = {
  posts: [],
};
const mutations = {
  setPosts(state, posts) {
    state.posts = posts;
  }
};
const actions = {
  loadPosts({ commit }) {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => resnponse.data)
      .then(posts => {
        commit("setPosts", posts);
        console.log(posts);
      });
  }
};
export default {
  //namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
};
```

In './store/index.js :

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";
import form from "./modules/form";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    form
  }

});
```

In ‘components/Posts.vue’ :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
            <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "PostsPage",
  computed: mapState(["posts"]),
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadPosts");
  },
};
</script>
```

Thank you so much if you can help me.

Comment: The first `.then()` in your `loadPosts()` action has a typo error: `response` becomes `resnponse.data` after the arrow. In this case `data` is `undefined`.

Comment: I have change it but it still doesn't work

Comment: What does your first `console.log(posts)` return?

Comment: It return JSON data object from API endpoint

Comment: Okay so it might come from the asynchronous operation itself. Did you try putting a `v-if="posts.length > 0"`in the outer `<div>` of your component ? It will not render until your posts data are ready.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm beginning to think that since he's using `modules` he should try

```
computed: mapState("form", ["posts"]),
```

(My rep is too low to add a comment :( )

Comment: This is actually not an answer, but you can post it in the comments :)

Comment: Cool, awesome! this is work for me. Additional ```this.$store.dispatch("form/loadPosts");``` in ```created()```

Comment: Not an answer. How does one access posts in template is what was expected afaik

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to vue js but you can try this in the component you want to render render the posts:

`import { mapState } from 'vuex';`

then
`computed: { ...mapState(['posts']) }`

Answer (score 0):

I am using one of the following way in my applications. It depends on your requirement. You can also try.

```
...mapState("form", ["posts"])
or
...mapState("form", {
  posts: state => state.posts
})
or
...mapState({
  posts: state => state.form.posts
}),
```